# AS3 Dynamically change image of object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How does one change image of already created object
Let's say I have an empty class named Icon and on runtime I want to change its image to something and add it on stage. The image can be from the library as another object or just a bitmap.

```
var icon1 = new Icon(myIcon);
...

public class Icon extends MovieClip {
public function Icon(icon:Class) {
    //change image
    addChild(this);
}
```

EDIT: in java I used to do it like this:

```
new Icon(myIcon);
...

public class Icon {

public Image image;
public String icon;

public Icon(String icon) {

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(icon + ".png"));
        image = ii.getImage();
        this.icon = icon;
    }
```

and on paint method I just type `icon1.image` to show on screen and also can change image if needed by accessing this variable.

Is this possible to do it something like this on as3?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `addChild(this)`? That won't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding your icons (image files) to your library, converting them to MovieClips and setting their AS linkage like this, for example :

[image]

You can use, for example, a `Sprite` object to load your icon inside your `Icon` class instance where your `Icon` class can be like this, for example :

```
package  {

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Icon extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _icon:Sprite;

        public function Icon(IconClass:Class): void
        {
            _icon = new IconClass();
            addChild(_icon);
        }

        public function changeIcon(IconClass:Class): void 
        {
            removeChild(_icon);
            _icon = new IconClass();
            addChild(_icon);
        }

    }

}
```

Then in your main code, you can use that class :

```
import Icon;

var icon:Icon = new Icon(PHPIcon);
addChild(icon);
```

then to change the icon, you've just to call the `changeIcon()` function :

```
icon.changeIcon(JSIcon).
```

**Edit :**

If you don't want to call `addChild()` to add your `Icon` class's instance to it's parent container, the constructor of your `Icon` class can be like this for example :

```
public function Icon(container:DisplayObjectContainer, IconClass:Class): void
{
    container.addChild(this);
    _icon = new IconClass();
    addChild(_icon);
}
```

then for its instance

```
var icon:Icon = new Icon(this, PHPIcon);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: If you've take the time to down vote my post, you can have some seconds to put why it's not useful and what's its problem. I know, it's maybe difficult to be honest, but trust me, just try ...

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your post, but it does work, pretty simple example is what I needed, I didn't give more details in my question, but all I wanted to do is utilize constructor to it's fullest, and not use workarounds, for example I just type `new Icon(myIcon)` and constructor takes care of the rest, the only problem now left is I still have to add another `addChild` from outside Icon class.

Comment: @Waras Oh, don't care about the down vote ... and about the `addChild()`, I edited my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I have an empty class named Icon and on runtime I want to
>   change its image to something

Before code make sure you prepared by following these example steps...

1) Open the **Library** (ctrl+L) and right click to choose "create new symbol" of MovieClip type and give it the name **Icon** then look at the **Advanced** tab further below...

2) Tick the box called "Export For ActionScript" and that should auto-fill a box called **Class** with text saying **Icon**. Click OK and you are ready.

3) Add one or two images to Library and right-click to choose "properties" and again like step (2) in the **linkage** section you tick the "Export for AS" option and give a name you prefer to type later via code. We'll assume you chose names like **Pic1** and **Pic2**. Notice as well that the "base Class" for these bitmaps is **bitmapData**? That's the data you change to update your image by code.

So to update dynamically by code... Create a bitmap and update its pixel data with any **bitmapData** from Library. Something like:

```
//# in your imports...
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Bitmap;    
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
import flash.utils.*;

....

//# in vars declarations...
public var my_icon : Icon = new Icon ();
public var my_BMP : Bitmap;
public var str_Type : String = ""; //later holds library object type for checks

....

//# later in your code
stage.addChild(my_icon); //looks invisible since empty

my_BMP = new Bitmap; //create new instance
my_icon.addChild ( my_BMP ); //add the empty bitmap into Icon

change_Icon ( Pic1 ); //parameter can be Library's Bitmap or Movieclip
```

### Making the `change_Icon` function...

If you just kept it bitmaps (PNG files?) you could use a simple function like this...

```
public function change_Icon ( in_Param : Class ) : void
{
    my_BMP.bitmapData = new in_Param as BitmapData; //replace pixels of existing bitmap container
}
```

But since you say it could be anything, sometimes a Bitmap or sometimes a MovieClip, well in that case you have to check the input and handle accordingly.

```
public function change_Icon ( in_Param : * ) : void
{
    //# Check the input type and handle it 
    str_Type = String ( getDefinitionByName( String( getQualifiedSuperclassName(in_Param) ) ) );

    if ( str_Type == "[class BitmapData]" )
    {
        trace ( "this object is a Bitmap..." );
        my_BMP.bitmapData = new in_Param as BitmapData; //replace pixels of existing bitmap container
    }

    if ( str_Type == "[class MovieClip]" )
    {
        trace ( "this object is a Movieclip..." );

        var temp_MC = new in_Param();
        var temp_BMD : BitmapData = new BitmapData( temp_MC.width, temp_MC.height );

        my_BMP.bitmapData = temp_BMD; //assign data to this bitmap
        temp_BMD.draw (temp_MC); //update by drawing
    }

}
```

Comment: yea addChild will just add object to the stage but what I'm looking for is a way to change image of the object itself or is this not possible?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your Java update previously. The Notifications jumped me  to your comment last time. I've tried my best to help with a newer update.

Comment: thats very informative solves some troubles working with different types of objects, but still this is a pretty complex function I guess I will have to figure it out later, wish there could be a simple way to changing image

Answer (score 0):

Thanks finally now I have a base class to work with on future projects, I also use `list` so all I have to do is call `new Icon(myIcon, x, y, this);`

```
package  {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

    public class Icon extends Sprite {
        public static var list:Array = new Array();
        private var icon:Sprite;
        private var n:int;

        public function Icon(IconClass:Class, x:int, y:int, container:DisplayObjectContainer):void {
            container.addChild(this);
            icon = new IconClass();
            n = list.push(this);
            addChild(icon);
            this.x = x; this.y = y;
        }
        public function changeIcon(IconClass:Class):void {
            removeChild(icon);
            icon = new IconClass();
            addChild(icon);
        }
        public function removeIcon():void {
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
            list.splice(n-1,1);
        }
    }
}
```